# SQL - Modify or Delete a Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I created triggers, and I can see them when I do SHOW TRIGGERS.  How is it possible to either modify or delete them?

I use MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter a trigger, while you have to drop it and then create the new one.
The drop syntax is

```
DROP TRIGGER trigger_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace trigger <trigger_name>
```

using above statement you can modify the trigger .

Answer (score 0):

delete trigger:

```
drop trigger trigger_name
```

modify trigger:

```
drop trigger trigger_name
create trigger trigger_name ...
```

There is currently no `alter trigger` at the moment. SO you have to drop and recreate a trigger if you want to modify it.

[TRIGGER SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)